# How to test a multi-threaded race scenario

Tags: c#, multithreading

I'm just now starting to learn multi-threading and I came across this question:

```
public class Program1
{
    int variable;
    bool variableValueHasBeenSet = false;

    public void Func1()
    {
        variable = 1;
        variableValueHasBeenSet = true;
    }

    public void Func2()
    {
        if (variableValueHasBeenSet) Console.WriteLine(variable);
    }
}
```

the questions is: Determine all possible outputs (in console) for the following code snippet if Func1() and Func2() are run in parallel on two separate threads. The answer given is nothing, 1 or 0. the first two options are obvious but the third one surprised me so I wanted to try and get it, this is what I tried:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    var prog1 = new Program1();
    List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();
    tasks.Add(new Task(() => prog1.Func2(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
    tasks.Add(new Task(() => prog1.Func1(), TaskCreationOptions.LongRunning));
    Parallel.ForEach(tasks, t => t.Start());
}
```

I couldn't get 0, only nothing and 1, so I was wondering what I'm doing wrong and how can I test this specific problem?

this is the explanation they provided for 0:

> 0 - This might seem impossible but this is a probable output and an interesting one. .Net runtime, C# and the CPU take the liberty of reordering instructions for optimization. So it is possible that variableValueHasBeenSet is set to true but the value of the variable is still zero. Another reason for such an output is caching. Thread2 might cache the value for the variable as 0 and will not see the updated value when Thread1 updates it in Func1. For a single threaded program this is not an issue as the ordering is guaranteed, but not so in multithreaded code. If the code at both the places is surrounded by locks, this problem can be mitigated. Another advanced way is to use memory barriers.

Comment: I've added the explanation which was provided regarding 0

Comment: Why do you want to test that? Or rather, let me ask me in another way: If you don't know about the ins and outs of instruction reordering, memory models, memory barriers (fences), etc., then how and where would you even start designing such a test? An analogue: If you don't know anything about electronics, how would you start designing a test jig for testing electronic circuits? Unless you have the profound knowledge to design such a test, stick with the explanation given...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> .Net runtime, C# and the CPU take the liberty of reordering
>   instructions for optimization.

**This bit of information is very important, because there is no guarantee the reordering  will happen at all**.

The optimizer will often reorder the instructions, but usually this is triggered by code complexity and will typically only occur on a *release* build (the optimizer will look for dependency-chains and may decide to reorder the code if no dependency is broken AND it will result in faster/more compact code).  The code complexity of your test is very low and may not trigger the reordering optimization.

The same thing *may* happen at the CPU level, if no dependency chains are found between CPU instructions, they may be reordered or at least run in parallel by a superscalar CPU, but other, simpler architectures will run code in-order.

> Another reason for such an output is caching. Thread2 might cache the
>   value for the variable as 0 and will not see the updated value when
>   Thread1 updates it in Func1

Again, this is is only a possibility. This type of optimization is typically triggered when repeatedly accessing a variable in a loop.   The optimizer may decide that it is faster to place the variable on a CPU register instead of accessing it from memory every iteration.

In any case, the amount of control you have over how the C# compiler emits its code is very limited, same goes for how the IL code gets translated to machine code. For these reasons, it would be very difficult for you to produce a reproducible test on every architecture for the case you intend to prove.

**What is really important is that you need to be aware that 1) the execution order of the instructions can never be taken for granted and 2)  variables may be temporarily stored in registers as a potential optimization. Once aware you should write your code defensively around these possibilities**